# How to pass variables from controller to view using codeignitor

Tags: codeigniter-3

I am trying to pass a variable(ans) from my controller (Add) to my view (add), but I am getting the error : undefined variable.

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined variable: ans
Filename: views/add.php
Line Number: 45
```

Here is my controller(Add.php)

```php
    <?php
    defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class Add extends CI_Controller {
        public function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->library('form_validation');
            $this->load->helper('form', 'date(%d-%m-%y)');
            $this->load->database();
            $this->load->model('add_model');
        }

        function index()
        {

            $this->load->view('add');
        }
        function date()
        {
            $datestring = '%Y %m %d - %h:%i %a';
            $time = time();
            echo mdate($datestring, $time);
        }
        function calculation()
        {
            $datestring = 'Day: %d Month: %m Year: %Y  - %h:%i %a';
            $time = time();
            $date=mdate($datestring, $time);
            //'user_registered' => mdate('%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s', now())
            //echo mdate($datestring, $time);
            if (isset($_POST['add'])) 
            {
                //$ans = array('ans' => $ans);
                $number2=200;
                $ans =$_POST['number1'] * $number2;
                $data=array( 'number1'=>$_POST['number1'],
                             'number2'=>$number2,
                             'ans'=>$ans,
                             'date'=>mdate('%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s', now())


                );
                //$ans = array('ans' => $ans);

            }
            $this->load->library('form_validation');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('number1', 'Number1', 'required|trim' );
            //$this->form_validation->set_rules('number2', 'Number2', 'required|trim' );
            if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
                $data = array('number1' =>  $this->input->post('number1'),
                              'answer' => $ans,
                              'date' => mdate('%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s', now())
                    );

                $id=$this->add_model->insert($data);
                if($id > 0)
                {
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('message',' stored in db');
                    echo $ans;

                }else{
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('message',' not stored in db');
                    //$this->load->view('add');

                }

            } 

            $this->load->view('add', $data);

        }
    }
```

My view (add.php)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <title>CustomerRegistrationForm</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!--<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>-->

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <br />
        <h3 align="center">Order With Us Now</h3>
        <br />
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">Order Form

            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <?php
                if($this->session->flashdata('message'))
                {
                    echo '
                    <div class="alert alert-success">'.$this->session->flashdata("message").'
                    </div>';
                }


                ?>
                <form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>add/calculation">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Enter quantity</label>
                        <input type="number" name="number1" id="number1" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter the quantity(minimium 50 kgs)" value="<?php echo set_value('number1'); ?>" />
                        <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('number1'); ?></span>
                    </div>  

                    <div>
                        <?php echo set_value('number2'); ?>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Answer</label>
                    <p class="text-success">
                        <?php echo $ans; ?>
                    </p>

                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="submit" name="add" value="Add" class="btn btn-info" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>welcome">HOME</a>

                    </div>  
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My model (Add_model.php)

```php
<?php
class Add_model extends CI_Model
{

    function insert($data)
    {
        $this->db->insert('calculation', $data);
        return $this->db->insert_id();
      //return $this->db->insert('users', $data);
    }
}
?>
```

kindly help me with this error.

Answer (score 0):

```
function calculation()
        {
            $datestring = 'Day: %d Month: %m Year: %Y  - %h:%i %a';
            $time = time();
            $date=mdate($datestring, $time);
            //'user_registered' => mdate('%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s', now())
            //echo mdate($datestring, $time);
            if (isset($_POST['add'])) 
            {
                //$ans = array('ans' => $ans);
                $number2=200;
                $number1 = $this->input->post('number1');
                $ans = $number1 * $number2;
                $data=array( 'number1'=>$number1,
                             'number2'=>$number2,
                             'ans'=>$ans,
                             'date'=>mdate('%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s', now())


                );
                //$ans = array('ans' => $ans);

            }
            $this->load->library('form_validation');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('number1', 'Number1', 'required|trim' );
            //$this->form_validation->set_rules('number2', 'Number2', 'required|trim' );
            if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
                $data = array('number1' =>  $this->input->post('number1'),
                              'answer' => $ans,
                              'date' => mdate('%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s', now())
                    );

                $id=$this->add_model->insert($data);
                if($id > 0)
                {
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('message',' stored in db');
                    echo $ans;

                }else{
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('message',' not stored in db');
                    //$this->load->view('add');

                }

            } 

            $this->load->view('add', $data);

        }
```